# Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1 error

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm running Xcode 6.4 and testing on an iPhone 6 with deployment target set to 8.4.

I'm setting up push notification for my app, and when I build, a Shell Script Invocation Error comes up: "**Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1**"

I have done my research and referred to [how to fix the issue "Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1" in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006464/how-to-fix-the-issue-command-bin-sh-failed-with-exit-code-1-in-iphone) for a solution. I looked at `Target -> Build-Phases -> RunScript` but I do not see a RunScript option in Xcode 6.4.

I'm reading the log, and this comes up:

> ../Build/Products/Debug-iphones/ios-app.app/Frameworks/Bond.framework: bundle format unrecognized, invalid or unsuitable

Does this have something to do with code signing? Earlier, I had an issue with code signing and clicked on the **Fix Issue** button, and that might have done something to my project?

*SIDE NOTE: The app runs on the simulator, but not on the iPhone.*

Comment: Seems that the bond.framework compilation. Have you tried to clear the derived data?

Comment: You can research this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620038/code-sign-error-command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1