# xCode 7 Cocoapod Archive error

Tags: cocoapods, xcode7

I have used cocoa pod and try to archive. After that, I got this error.

I looked solution from here but it doesn't work too. How shall I do?

[how to fix the issue "Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1" in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006464/how-to-fix-the-issue-command-bin-sh-failed-with-exit-code-1-in-iphone)

```
sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
building file list ... done
rsync: push_dir#3 "/Users/khantthulinn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SMRTConnect-emozrftvltrpagajdyydwrdgnacg/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SMRTConnect/InstallationBuildProductsLocation" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-47/rsync/main.c(580) [receiver=2.6.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (8 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-47/rsync/io.c(453) [sender=2.6.9]
```

Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 12