# Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1 while archive

Tags: objective-c, xcode, shell

Application is building and installing but not archiving. Yes I found some answers related to this issue but didn't work for me and this is the one of them "[how to fix the issue "Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1" in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006464/how-to-fix-the-issue-command-bin-sh-failed-with-exit-code-1-in-iphone)", I checked the Run script in Build Phases and tried deleting the DerivedData folder in Library but nothing worked. Please help me in this

Xcode-8.3

Comment: Did you tried to Clean the project and then run it? For me it works when I receive that error when building/archiving one of my macOS projects.

Comment: @vitormm Yes so many times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying for some days my project successfully archived, The reason is I was running shell command behind the proxy. Yes because of proxy it was not working, once I removed the proxy and tried to archive it worked smoothly.

Thanks

Comment: How to remove proxy?

Comment: GoTo->System preferences-> Network-> Advanced-> on top proxies, You can enable and disable