# Alamofire.framework: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff in 2 iOS apps

Tags: ios, alamofire

So I have been using Alamofire in 2 of my iOS projects for years, and suddenly both give me the following error when I Archive:   Alamofire.framework: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff

I have updated my cocapods and run pod update, no luck.  Any ideas?  There has been no changes to the app or the frameworks before the error - no script changes or anything.   And it only happens when I archive or compile to my iPhone, not when compile it to run in on the simulator.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! It'd really helpful if you describe your error more specifically, include: what is you expected result, what you've been trying, what is actually happening, and also include the part of your code triggering that error. In the specific case of XCode try to put breakpoints in your app to isolate the code is triggering the issues.

Comment: I am just trying to get the app to run.  The Alamo fire code is used in several places in my app, all that worked before (for the past 2 years) and has not changed.  I believe this error is caused by the Alamofire framework, or maybe with the certificates or something - because it compiles fine to the simulator and only errors out when I run it either on the phone or try to Archive it.   It does not point to any of my code when production the error.

Comment: It fails with: Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Comment: Check the target OS versions for your project and the Alamofire, Swift and Xcode versions you're using. Perform a project clean (Command+K), then try to run with a debugger attached to a physical device. Are you using Cocoapods or Carthage?

Comment: Xcode 9.4.1,  Swift 3.3,  AlamoFire 4.7.  Cocapods.
I did a clean and cleaned the derivated  data. 
Interesting twist:   I remove AlamoFire (just took it out of the POD File and ran "pod Install"  - and now I get the exact same error from the BOLTS framework.

Comment: And of course commented out the 'Alamofile' code

Comment: Actually, this solved it (section 39) - For some reason when I locked my keychain - then Archived, it asked for my password to unlock it and that cleared it up. I am guessing there was something strange with my keychain.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006464/how-to-fix-the-issue-command-bin-sh-failed-with-exit-code-1-in-iphone

Comment: (In the attached Stackoverflow it was solved by section 39)